# PHP function to properly Parse XML element that contains one child element for each item in the array

Tags: php, arrays, xml-parsing

I'm searching for either an existing or custom function that can parse an XML string like so:

```
<root>
    <products>
        <product>
            <sku>001</sku>
            <name>Product 1</name>
        </product>
        <product>
            <sku>002</sku>
            <name>Product 2</name>
        </product>
    </products>
</root>
```

into an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 001
                    [name] => Product 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 002
                    [name] => Product 2
                )

        )

)
```

I've been using the below to get a nice array out of the XML:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($xml)), true);
```

but as you can see the array comes out kind of funky with that additional "product" key in there:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 001
                            [name] => Product 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [sku] => 002
                            [name] => Product 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This function should be able to parse any size xml and properly format arrays in the same way without knowing any of the element names. For my case I do not need to worry about collecting any attributes or anything like that.

I've been toying with the idea of creating a function that uses Xpath when parsing the arrays but have not yet been successful in creating/finding one that works as desired.

Comment: well thats the structure to be expected since you got the parent `products` and inside it several `product` nodes, maybe you can just iterate inside the xml and make your own structure and push it inside another container, then your desired structure can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function I started using a while back when converting XML content to arrays.

Full description can be found here:
https://totaldev.com/flatten-multidimensional-arrays-php/

For your example you should be able to use it like this:

```
// Flatten an array of data with full-path string keys
function flat($array, $separator = '|', $prefix = '', $flattenNumericKeys = false, $appendNumericArrayKeys = true) {
    $result = [];

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $separatorKey = (empty($prefix) ? '' : $separator) . $key;
        $valueIsNumericArray = is_array($value) && count(array_filter(array_keys($value), 'is_string')) < 1;
        if($appendNumericArrayKeys === false && $valueIsNumericArray) $separatorKey = '';
        $new_key = $prefix . $separatorKey;

        // Make sure value isn't empty
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(empty($value)) $value = null;
            else if(count($value) == 1 && isset($value[0]) && is_string($value[0]) && empty(trim($value[0]))) $value = null;
        }

        $hasStringKeys = is_array($value) && count(array_filter(array_keys($value), 'is_string')) > 0;
        if(is_array($value) && ($hasStringKeys || $flattenNumericKeys)) $result = array_merge($result, flat($value, $separator, $new_key, $flattenNumericKeys, $appendNumericArrayKeys));
        else $result[$new_key] = $value;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

It basically flattens the array you have from your XML into an array with keys that are the string path to the elements.  You would use it like this:

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($xml)), true);
$flattenedArray = flat($arr, '|', '', false, false);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($flattenedArray, true).'</pre>';
```

The output of the flattened array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 001
                    [name] => Product 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 002
                    [name] => Product 2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It's close but not quite. Remove "|product" from the key and it'd be there but it's still just not quite what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I made an adjustment to the function that adds an additional parameter `$appendNumericArrayKeys`.  Setting that param to `false` should get you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this @matt! I ended up finding out that these typo of simple xml arrays are supposed to be parsed using Xpath. It still didn't do exactly what I needed but at least I know what the deal was. That sort of changed my need for this but since it does what I asked I can sure accept this answer..